# How to create a cache-preventing link? Using random number? Unix time? or other better options?

Tags: php, web-api, websites

For example, sometimes I need to generate a link, but I don't want someone cache the context by url of the same link (e.g.:I don't want Facebook feed dialog to cache the page context), so I need something like this:

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?app_id=(my app id)&link=http://(my website)/myContextToShare/(some random string)
```

which

```
(some random string)
```

is added to avoid Facebook caches the old context of myContextToShare, and my result link may look like this:

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?app_id=(my app id)&link=http://(my website)/myContextToShare/355917183
```

. My question is, what should "(some random string)" be? Assuming I'm using php, should it be:

```
<?php echo rand(); ?>
```

?

```
<?php echo time(); ?>
```

?

or other better options?

Comment: What you are trying to achieve is being able to track how often your site was visited?

Answer (score 5):

It's probably better to use [cache-controlling HTTP headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cache-Control) rather than generating lots of unique URLs.